How to avoid redundant configurations.all attribute declaration in Gradle multi-module project?
I'm working on a Gradle multi-module project where Service A (the library module) depends on the latest version of Guava (33.1.0-jre). To ensure proper Guava functionality, Service A's build.gradle includes the following attributes:
configurations.all {
    attributes {
        attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.jvm.environment", String::class.java), "standard-jvm")
    }
}

However, Service B (which has an implementation in build.gradle of service A) encounters a resolution error when these attributes are missing from its build.gradle. The error message indicates that Gradle cannot choose between incompatible variants of Guava due to the missing org.gradle.jvm.environment attribute.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':B:compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':B:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-jre.
     Required by:
         project :police-agency-information-client
      > The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-jre:
          - androidApiElements
          - jreApiElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'androidApiElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:33.1.0-jre and com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-jre declares an API of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'android' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
          - Variant 'jreApiElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:33.1.0-jre and com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-jre declares an API of  a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn'compatibility  say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')

Is there a way to inherit or propagate this attribute(attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.jvm.environment", String::class.java), "standard-jvm")) from service A to service B, avoiding having to duplicate them in module B's build.gradle file?
I only want to have an implementation of service A in service B, without any additional attributes etc.
If inheritance is not possible, what are the recommended approaches to ensure consistent configuration between modules in a multi-module Gradle project?

What plugins do you have applied in Service A and Service B? If you are working in a JVM environment, then if those services use eg the Kotlin JVM or Java Library plugins those plugins will take care of the attributes for you

@SimonJacobs Service A has a guava version 33.1.0-jre implementation in build.gradle, for which I had to define an attribute with org.gradle.jvm.environment as standard-jvm as here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/26f7c82d4c49f0f583ea416174d3711214dc9f75/build.gradle.kts#L80-L90
Service B implements service A, and when service B is building, it is expecting to define in build.gradle also org.gradle.jvm.environment as standard-jvm for the guava implemented in service A - something I would like to avoid.

Yep, I understand the question :) My point is this can most simply be done by adding appropriate plugins to Service A and Service B and then you can avoid tinkering with attributes. Could you please confirm what Gradle plugins are added to Service A and Service B projects and then I can make sure this approach works in your case.

In service A I have mainly the standard ones: id("idea"), kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22", in B: "org.springframework.boot", "io.spring.dependency-management", "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa", "plugin.spring". But I can't add any new plugins for other services, because service A is implemented by many other services that I have no control over. So service A has to be independent :(

I've written an answer so you know where I'm coming from. However it's not clear to me how you are writing code and importing dependencies in Service B without the Java or Kotlin JVM plugin applied. Without these, I don't see how that project even has an implementation configuration based on the plugins you've listed.

A couple of initial points to be totally clear:

When you declare Guava as a direct dependency of Service A, Gradle looks to the setup of Service A's Configuration objects1 when building Service A.
When you declare Service A as a direct dependency of Service B, Guava becomes a transitive dependency of Service B. Service B assumes responsibility for obtaining Guava and Gradle looks to Service B's Configuration objects when building Service B.

There are four ways I can think of to deal with this:

The recommended one is to apply a plugin in each project which sets up that project's Configuration objects with the correct attributes to pick up the correct library versions (in this case Guava). Such a plugin would normally be needed to write and compile code in any case. The Java plugin and the Kotlin JVM plugin would do this for you.
You could add the attribute to Guava when importing it into Service A. This will then tell Service B what attributes it should look for when importing the library. I've set out how this would work below.
You add the attributes "by hand", as you are doing at present2. If necessary, you could add such code to your own convention plugin to make sharing it around your project easier.
You create a "fat JAR" in Service A, which packages Service As dependencies together so Service B doesn't have to resolve them itself. This is not recommended.

In your case, it looks like you are developing in Kotlin on the JVM. Therefore I suggest you apply the Kotlin JVM plugin in Service B so Gradle knows which flavour of Guava to download in Service B. I confess though I am unsure how you are writing code and declaring dependencies in that project without having done so already.
Addendum: Add attribute in the project declaring the dependency
To show this, you could declare Guava like this in Service A:
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-jre") {
        attributes {
            attribute(
                TargetJvmEnvironment.TARGET_JVM_ENVIRONMENT_ATTRIBUTE,
                objects.named(TargetJvmEnvironment, TargetJvmEnvironment.STANDARD_JVM)
            )
        }
    }
}


1 Configuration being a Gradle concept. implementation is a Configuration added by the Java plugin (and also the Kotlin JVM plugin which does so by applying the Java plugin).
2 I do not believe this is necessary in Service A at present though, as you are using the Kotlin JVM plugin
